# Azure AD B2C Application not available when signInAudience = AzureADMyOrg or AzureADMultipleOrgs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm new to Azure AD B2C so I'm not fully certain of its capabilities. Either way, I'm trying to limit the access to one of my registered applications to users from the same AD B2C tenant (single-tenant scenario). The only way I was able to do this was through the App registrations (Preview), the Legacy Application registration doesn't seem to support this.

Once I set the single-tenant option, the application starts to appear under the Owned Applications tab on the App registrations (Preview) blade but I cannot make use of it. Whenever I try to run a default or custom flow I get this error:

> The provided application with ID 'XXXXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX' is not
>   valid against this service. Please use an application created via the
>   B2C portal and try again.

I also tried to set the multi-tenant scenario (AzureADMultipleOrgs) but I still get the same error. The only way I can make this work is by using the AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount which leaves the app open to everyone and that's not what I need.

Am I missing an extra configuration or is this still not supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the B2C specific Application Registration option for it to be compatible with Azure AD B2C User Flows or Custom Policies. If you then need to further restrict the user base who should be able to login to the application, then you would need to implement some RBAC, see this sample:https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac

In AAD B2C, the Application Role assignment and Application Assignment is not honored, these are Azure AD concepts that are not respected by Azure AD B2C auth policies.